Is there a way to change the Eclipse / Repast Simphony tmp folder's path to an external drive's folder without breaking paths to local computer files?
I am using Eclipse IDE for simulation runs with Repast Simphony on a Windows machine. Because my local machine's tmp directory tends to fill up very quickly during experimentation, I would like to change the default tmp directory to reside on a larger (~2 TB) external drive. I have made the change by using the VM argument -Djava.io.tmpdir per How can I modify the temporary file path used to support repast simphony batch runs?, making my tmp directory be an existing folder on the external drive (mapped to F: on my machine - e.g., F:/repast_simphony_runs_tmp). This results in an error for finding local paths on my C: drive, though.
Within my repast simphony code's ContextCreator file, I reference some other files present on my C: drive to pull in some extra user-defined input parameter values at the beginning of experimentation - e.g., file C:/Users/Username/RepastModel/data/ParamFile.JSON5. Ordinarily (without the tmp file argument), pulling in data from this JSON5 file works without any issues. However, when I use the -Djava.io.tmpdir argument to change the tmp directory to be on my F: drive, the model is unable to find the JSON5 file on my C: drive. I have been using relative file paths (e.g., private String JSON5Path = "./data/ParamFile.JSON5" in the ContextCreator file), but using an absolute file path to the JSON5 file also did not resolve the issue.
Is there any obvious reason that the setting of the -Djava.io.tmpdir argument to my external F: drive would be breaking file paths referencing my local C: drive? (Note - when the tmpdir argument is not used, the JSON5 file is found as usual. The error only seems to happen when I use the argument to reference a location on my external F: drive.)

When you use the absolute paths, what errors are you getting? FileNotFound? Can you post the details. That might help to narrow it down.

I have an error catcher for a FileNotFoundException, such that it results in the following when it sees that FileNotFoundException:
System.err.println("Couldn't find run definition JSON5 file... Skipping and using default!");
So, the error is a FileNotFoundException. The exception only occurs when I am using the VM arg to change the tmp directory to be on external drive F:, though.
Again, I use a rel path to an file private String JSON5Path = "./data/ParamFile.JSON5"; before referencing later - the file does exist on my machine. I tried an abs file path without success, either.

In the error, is there anything strange about the path of the file it's trying to open. I mean in the stack trace where it references the file it can't find.

Well, today the error seems to have disappeared with a new batch experimental run as mysteriously as it had appeared, with no apparent change of anything other than restarting the machine overnight. I was able to run a few of the same batch experiments to completion today while using an external drive to hold temp files. Perhaps the restart did something (although I had also restarted the night before last without resolving the issue). So, I guess this issue is overcome by events, at least for now. Hopefully the issue won't reappear. Thanks for your feedback regardless, @NickCollier.
